# Timeout error when trying to test ionic app with selenium+protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, ionic-framework

`Error: Angular could not be found on the page index.html : retries looking for angular exceeded`

I'm getting this error after I followed the ionic tutorial for setting up protractor.

Here's my protractor-conf.js:

```js
exports.config = {
          capabilities: {
                  // You can use other browsers
                  // like firefox, phantoms, safari, IE (-_-)
                  'browserName': 'chrome' 
          },

          // chromeDriver: ['./node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver'],

          specs: [
                   // We are going to make this file in a minute
                'e2e/specs.js'
          ],
          jasmineNodeOpts: {
                  showColors: true,
                 defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
                isVerbose: true,
          },
        allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
          onPrepare: function(){
                browser.driver.get('http://localhost:3000');
        }
};
```

I noticed in another tutorial, it had me give it a pointer to the selenium server. Maybe that's the problem?

I added the chromeDriver line in there, but it broke it even more, so I commented it out

Also, I have ionic serve up and running like the tutorial says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the ionic server address `localhost:8100/app` to the baseURL property in protractor configuration file